# What is the Metadata API name for Knowledge Setting "Enable list of cases linked to an article in Salesforce Classic (Classic Only)"?

Tags: metadata-api, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

Does anyone know the Metadata API setting for "Enable list of cases linked to an article in Salesforce Classic (Classic Only)" under Knowledge Settings?

I can not find it under https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_knowledgesettings.htm

Is this setting not available to be the Metadata API?  Is there another way to ensure this is enabled when deploying to an org?

Comment: I suggest to raise a case with support . Looks like this is missed in documentation and don't see metadata for this. should go under not supported !!!

Answer (score 0):

When you pull KnowledgeSettings.answers via the metadata API, it has a key `enableKnowledgeCaseRL` which I'm guessing is the key. RL = Related List